# Python - Google App Engine - Get model ID in Dict

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, dictionary

In my Google App Engine - Python app, I've got a to_dict() to allow JSON serialization of my models.

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
  createdOn = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  createdBy = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
  modifiedOn = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  modifiedBy = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)

  def to_dict(self):
    return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
```

How do I ensure that modelInstance.key().id() is part of the dict, hence part of the JSON object?

Comment: So your wanting the primary key field to be of this dictionary?

Comment: The datastore needs to be able to store dicts.  There are work arounds but [Google](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=805) already has a feature request for this.  If you are interested in having this functionality go vote by clicking the star next the issue number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's A handy `to_dict` method in `ext.db`, you could update your method to something like:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    def to_dict(self):
        return db.to_dict(self, {'id':self.key().id()})
```

You might want to check if your model is is_saved before trying to get the id though.